# How to get the total count of entities in a kind in Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have a kind having around 5 Million entities in the Google Cloud Datastore. I want to get this count programmatically using Java. I tried following code but it work upto certain threshold (800K). 
When i ran query for 5 M records, it goes into infinite loop (my guess) since it doesn't returns any count. How to get the count of entities for this big data? I would not like to use Google App Engine API since it requires to setup environment.

```java
private static Datastore datastore;

datastore = DatastoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService(); 

Query query = Query.newKeyQueryBuilder().setKind(kind).build();

int count = Iterators.size(datastore.run(query)); //count has the entities count
```

Comment: You should be able to achieve this using apache beam. [This](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/cookbook/datastore_wordcount.py) is an example to count words. You can change the code to get record count instead.
However, this will take up lot of resources and time. This is not recommended if you need to get counts regularly.

Comment: I have implemented it using Apache Beam, but like mentioned it cant be used to get the counts regularly and even the job runs for a long time when deployed on GCP. Hence cant be used for real time counts.

Answer (score 1):

How accurate do you need the count to be?  For an slightly out of date count you can use a [stats entity](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/stats) to fetch the number of entities for a kind.

If you can't use the stale counts from the stats entity, then you'll need to keep counter entities for the real time counts that you need.  You should consider using a [sharded counter](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters).

Comment: I need the exact count currently in a kind. Also if I use the above query, I don't even get a result. It just goes in infinite loop or query times out for big data.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Google Dataflow. A pipeline like the following should do it:

```
def send_count_to_call_back(callback_url):
    def f(record_count):
        r = requests.post(callback_url, data=json.dumps({
            'record_count': record_count,
        }))
    return f

def run_pipeline(project, callback_url)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions.from_dictionary({
        'project': project,
        'runner': 'DataflowRunner',
        'staging_location':'gs://%s.appspot.com/dataflow-data/staging' % project,
        'temp_location':'gs://%s.appspot.com/dataflow-data/temp' % project,
        # .... other options
    })

    query = query_pb2.Query()
    query.kind.add().name = 'YOUR_KIND_NAME_GOES HERE'

    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
    _ = (p
     | 'fetch all rows for query' >> ReadFromDatastore(project, query)
     | 'count rows' >> apache_beam.combiners.Count.Globally()
     | 'send count to callback' >> apache_beam.Map(send_count_to_call_back(callback_url))
    )
```

I use python, but they have a Java sdk too https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/

The only issue is your process will have to trigger this pipeline, let it run on its own for a few minutes, and then let it hit a callback URL to let you know it's done

Comment: Hi, I already deployed the solution you mentioned using the google dataflow. But for big data, the query for the count terminates without executing completely, hence giving the incorrect count of entities. Another disadvantage is scaling, when construct a pipeline, I used Pcollection with one element, in which query is wriiten in ParDo, and trigger the pipeline. Only one worked get assigned and job takes a long time to execute. One way, i found a solution is by fetching the enetities in batches. That worked for me !

Answer (score 0):

[COUNT aggregation in datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/aggregation-queries) is generally available now.

There are client libraries available in multiple languages which support this particular feature.

With this feature, users can avoid performing the client side aggregations which puts an additional burden of increased egress cost. Also no need of using alternatives like [cloud-functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation#solution_cloud_functions) to update the aggregate values on the backend side which as a cost limitation of their own.